# Plesk doesn't show all databases?

Tags: sql, linux, centos, mysql, plesk

My Plesk control panel shows only 3 databases (2 for one domain and 1 databases for the second).

When I use command line `mysql> show databases`, it shows around 20 databases.

Why is there a difference between Plesk `mysql> show databases;` when it comes to listing all databases on my CentOS 8 system?

When I do backup with Plesk, does it backup all or just 3 databases?

Comment: `mysql -u admin -p`cat/etc/psa/.psa.shadow` psa`
`select * from data_bases;`

If this returns empty then you have to recreate the databses from plesk or insert the records manually(I wouldnt recommend the second.)

Comment: Thanks. Could you check the command line, it doesn't work here.

Comment: which command not work? first is "mysql -u admin -p`cat/etc/psa/.psa.shadow` psa" and second is `select * from data_bases`

Comment: if you still issue then please look at following http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?93709-Plesk-shows-0-mysql-databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I do backup with Plesk, does it backup all or just 3 databases?

Yes, it backup only databases which are created by Plesk.

Answer (score 0):

```
when you go from Plesk is shown only your database, which one created and owner of you.
```

and

```
 when you go from command line then it's display all database whose are not 
created or owner by you. But it's accessible to other's database where you not
owner of database.
```